# Open selected file from treeview in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, path, treeview, richtextbox

My application consists of a TreeView a RichTextBox and a Button.
The TreeView displays contents(directories, folders and files) of my system.
The Button when pressed is supposed to take the selected file from the TreeView and display it in the RichTextBox.
I have used the following code:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = TreeView.SelectedNode.FullPath;           
        MessageBox.Show(a);  //To check if it's taking the correct path
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(a, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
```

The value in the string a is correct, that is `TreeView.SelectedNode.FullPath` returns the correct path which I confirm with the MessageBox.

However there is a runtime exception in the `richTextBox1.LoadFile(a, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)` line. 
It appends the path of the Debug folder before the actual selected file path([shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqWj.png)), which leads to an exception.
All the files are stored locally.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where are your files stored? I guess not in the directory on your screen.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom The treeView displays all available files on my system. The result is same for a file in the same directory or a file in some other location. The debug folder path gets appended even if the files to be opened. Shown in the image [link](http://i65.tinypic.com/plx5k.png)

Comment: @MightyBadaboom solved the issue.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your tree nodes contains **relative** path to item instead of **absolute**.

How to prevent it? At first, you should store the full path (include drive name) in `FullPath` property.

If the path starts with the folder name, application tries to get the inner folder of current active folder (Debug). If the path starts with `\` - app will seek the file in the root folder of current drive, if the path starts with drive name `D:\` - app will seek the file on this drive. So, in your case, it will be better to pass absolute path always, it will exclude ambiguity while searching the file.

If the file should be stored relatively to the executive file, you should add some `..\` as prefix - it stands for 'going one level upper'

You can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#MS-DOS.2FMicrosoft_Windows_style) to get more familiar with windows pathname style.

Comment: I am sorry for having a weak software background, but how to I store the full path (including drive names) in the FullPath property.

Comment: I understood the problem but I still can't really get to the solution. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: How do you set the FullPath property at the moment and how do you initialize the TreeView? When we could see your sourcecode it is easier to help you.

Comment: I do not know how do you fill the nodes, so I can not help you here. If my answer helps you, please upvote it:)

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov I am new and my upvotes don't count yet, thank's for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After some research and trials I found the solution to this issue.

The reason behind this problem is that the code `TreeView.SelectedNode.FullPath` returns the path with an incorrect syntax. 
Suppose the file you've selected in the TreeView has the path `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.txt`

`TreeView.SelectedNode.FullPath` will return the path: `C\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.txt` which is syntactically incorrect i.e. it cannot be used directly in some other part of code.

The solution which I went for is, putting this output into a temporary string, and inserting `:\\` in the 2nd place(1st index), thus making the syntax correct.(C:\\Users...)

Putting up the code I used just for reference:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = TreeView.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString();
    string b = ":\\";
    string c = a.Insert(1, b);
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(c, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
}
```

Hope this helps. Thank you for the assistance I received while solving this problem.